# Add links in Left navigation menu dynamically in angular2 by any event in other component

Tags: angular

In my application. There is dropdown in the header shows available apps.
When someone selects one of the apps from the dropdown i want like:-

In left navigation according to app selection Views will have links added dynamically. i.e. if app3 is selected from the dropdown in header if there are available navigation, it should create links in Views marked by arrow.

[image]

**Code for navigation.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CustomViewNavigationComponent} from './custom-view-navigation.component';
import {CookieService} from 'angular2-cookie/core';

@Component({

  selector: 'sa-navigation',
  templateUrl: 'navigation.component.html',
  providers: [CustomViewNavigationComponent, CookieService]
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

In it's Template added

```
<custom-view-navigation></custom-view-navigation>
```

for creating navigation.

**Code for custom-view-navigation.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {JsonApiService} from "../../../shared/api/json-api.service";
import {CookieService} from 'angular2-cookie/core';
import {Message} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router'
import {CustomViewNavigationComponent} from "../../navigation/custom-view-
navigation.component"


@Component({
    selector: 'custom-view-navigation',
    templateUrl: 'custom-view-navigation.component.html',
    providers: [JsonApiService, CookieService]
})
export class CustomViewNavigationComponent implements OnInit {
    forms = [];
    msgs: Message[] = [];
    constructor(private _jsonApiService: JsonApiService, private _cookieService: CookieService,
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _router: Router) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getCompletedFormViews();
    }
    getCompletedFormViews() {
        var getViews = () => {
            var appID = this._cookieService.get("AppID")
            this.msgs.push({ severity: 'success', summary: 'App Delete', detail: 'App deleted successfully.' });
            this._jsonApiService.getViewsByAppID(appID).subscribe((forms) => {
                this.forms = forms;
            });
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            getViews();
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

In it's Template

```
<li>
    <a title="Views">
        <span class="menu-item-parent">{{'Views' | i18n}}</span>
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let form of forms">
             <!--<a (click)="linkClicked(form._id)" routerLink="/completed/all/{{form._id}}">{{form.name | i18n}}</a>-->
            <a   routerLink="/completed/all/{{form._id}}">{{form.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**code in available-apps.component.ts**

```
    import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'sa-available-apps',
        templateUrl: 'available-apps.component.html'
    })
    export class AvailableAppsComponent implements OnInit {

        constructor(){

        }
        ngOnInit()
        { }
       setCookies(event) {
          var renderView=new CustomViewNavigationComponent(this.jsonApiService,this._cookieService,null,this._router);
        renderView.getCompletedFormViews();
    }

    }
```

In it's template i have dropdown:-

```
<p-dropdown [options]="listtodisplayindropdown" filter="filter"
                 [(ngModel)]="selectedApp" (onChange)="setCookies($event)"></p-dropdown>
```

Please suggest me if there is code structure issue. and what is the way to solve this issue?

Comment: "and what is the way to solve this issue? " ---> which issue ?

Comment: i added a method in available.apps.component.ts which instantiates custom-view-navigation.component.ts class by passing all arguments and then called the method getCompletedFormViews(). although it gets latest data from the api but does not reflect to the ui where i have used *ngFor to create navigation.

Comment: Please, add this to your question otherwise, it will get deleted because of being unclear.

Comment: I have added that code @n00dl3 please take a look.

Comment: I'm talking about the issue you are experiencing, you don't state about it once in your question, except in the title which is quite vague.

Answer (score 0):

I completed this task like:-

In available-app.component.ts in setCookies() method

```
     setCookies(event) {
            this.getCustomviews(event.value);
    }
 getCustomviews(selectedAppID) {
        this.jsonApiService.getViewsByAppID(selectedAppID).subscribe((forms) => {
                CustomViewNavigationComponent.getCustomViews(forms);
            });
    }
```

and in custom-view-navigation.component.ts added a static method

```
static that;
    constructor() {
           CustomViewNavigationComponent.that=this;
    }

    static getCustomViews(forms)
        {
            console.log(CustomViewNavigationComponent.that);
            CustomViewNavigationComponent.that.forms=forms;
        }
```

It worked.